# Getting subentity vertex points of solid in AutoCAD

Tags: c#, autocad

I am trying to find the vertex points of a swept polyline.
So i have a solid that was created by sweeping a circle along a 3D polyline.
It looks like that:[image of sweeped solid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cd6Ew.png)

Googeling the whole of friday last week i think i have to play around with the subentity part. I found out how to change the color of the subentity edges for instance, but couldnt for christs sake not find out how to access the geometric

This is what i tried out so far, but as i noted right at the bottom i am kinda lost there:

```
    [CommandMethod("SubEntExample")]
    public void SubEntExample()
    {
        Document doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument;
        Database db = doc.Database;
        Editor ed = doc.Editor;

        PromptEntityOptions peo = new PromptEntityOptions("\nSelect a 3D solid: ");
        peo.SetRejectMessage("\nInvalid selection...");
        peo.AddAllowedClass(typeof(Solid3d), true);

        PromptEntityResult per = ed.GetEntity(peo);

        if (per.Status != PromptStatus.OK)
            return;

        using (Transaction Tx = db.TransactionManager.StartTransaction())
        {
            Solid3d solid = Tx.GetObject(per.ObjectId, OpenMode.ForWrite) as Solid3d;

            ObjectId[] ids = new ObjectId[] { per.ObjectId };

            FullSubentityPath path = new FullSubentityPath(ids, new SubentityId(SubentityType.Null, IntPtr.Zero));

            List<SubentityId> subEntIds = new List<SubentityId>();

            using (Autodesk.AutoCAD.BoundaryRepresentation.Brep brep =
                new Autodesk.AutoCAD.BoundaryRepresentation.Brep(path))
            {                    
                foreach (Autodesk.AutoCAD.BoundaryRepresentation.Edge edge in brep.Edges)
                {
                    subEntIds.Add(edge.SubentityPath.SubentId);
                }                    
            }

            foreach (SubentityId subentId in subEntIds)
            {

                *** here i am lost ***

            }
            Tx.Commit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: How about exporting the entity to DXF and looking at the makeup of the data in the text file? It might explain to you the mechanics of the sub entities. I don't have specific knowledge of the case in hand, but, if they are "id's" then would you next what to "open" those id's? These would return suitable objects that provide the coordinate data. But that is a guess. Looking at the DXF might show you more information. Perhaps you could add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my first solution involved getting all the grips and deciding which are relevant, but thank to a bit of help from the internet ( :) ) i came up with a way better solution

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if there are boundaryreps that are marked as elliptical or circular arcs
    /// returns true if we found at least 2 of those points
    /// also stores the points in a referenced Point3dCollection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="solid"></param>
    /// <param name="pts"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private bool GetSweepPathPoints(Solid3d solid, ref Point3dCollection pts)
    {
        // create boundary rep for the solid
        using (Brep brep = new Brep(solid))
        {
            // get edges of the boundary rep
            BrepEdgeCollection edges = brep.Edges;
            foreach (Edge edge in edges)
            {
                // get the nativ curve geometry of the edges and then 
                // check if it is a circle
                // for more info look at:
                // http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2012/08/retrieving-native-curve-geometry-using-brep-api.html
                Curve3d curv = ((ExternalCurve3d)edge.Curve).NativeCurve;
                if (curv is CircularArc3d)
                {
                    // transform curved arch into circle and add it to the colecction 
                    // (if not in it alreadz)
                    CircularArc3d circle = curv as CircularArc3d;
                    if (!pts.Contains(circle.Center)) pts.Add(circle.Center);
                }
            }
        }
        return (pts.Count > 1) ? true : false;
    }
```

I call the whole thing the following way then

```
            Point3dCollection pts = new Point3dCollection();
            // only do the whole thing if we face a swept solid
            if (GetSweepPathPoints(sld, ref pts))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < pts.Count; i++)
                {
                    ed.WriteMessage("\nPt[{0}] = {1}", i, pts[i]);
                }
            }
```